# When making my collection class Iterable (implementing Iterable) what do I have in the iterator() method?

Tags: java, generics, interface, generic-list, iterable

I've read so many tutorials, but they all seem to have so many differing contents for the inside of the `iterator()` method. I have a class that holds many Animals, so I have it `implements Iterable<Animal>` as they're `Animal` objects, but what do I return in `public Iterator<Animal> iterator() { ... }`? I want to be able to use it in a for-each loop.

Comment: You need to return an `Iterator` implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if it has many `Animals`, you will want to return an `Iterator<Animal>`. Try this code, for starters:

```
public Iterator<Animal> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Animal>() {
        public boolean hasNext() {
            // your code here
        }
        public Animal next() {
            // your code here
        }
        public void remove() {
            // you really don't need to do anything here unless you want to
        }
    }
}
```

If you already store the `Animal`s in an array, you can use just one line of code:

```
public Iterator<Animal> iterator() {
    return Arrays.asList(yourAnimalArray).iterator();
}
```

And if you store it in any type of `Collection<Animal>` (such as an `ArrayList`):

```
public Iterator<Animal> iterator() {
    return yourAnimalCollection.iterator();
}
```